# How to find a range of cells? Excel C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel, excel-interop

I have to find all the cells with needed value by my C# program. These cells are disordered and disperced like you see at the example below the text (I've selected them by using search tool at the toolbar).

All what i need is to select cells with needed value in a varible (to change their color).

[image: https://s16.postimg.org/x5dahxlwl/image.png]

Comment: What have you tried? I would think you would need to get a range of “used” cells. Otherwise when do you stop?  A Range of “used” cells would give you a range to loop thru cell by cell checking for your values and changing the color when necessary. To get all the “used” cells in a sheet:  Excel.Range  usedRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange… usedRange will be the cells you need to search thru. Foreach (Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows) etc… anyway its best to show what you have tried.

Comment: @JohnG i'll give you a pice of my code after night. Thx for response.

Comment: Or... since you have access to the excel file... you could also use its search features...

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheet sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Range rng = sheet.UsedRange;
foreach (Range column in from Range row in rng.Rows from Range column in row.Columns where column.Value == "T" select column)
{
   column.Interior.Color = Color.Red;
}
```

This piece of code will select the active worksheet, select the entire used range, iterate through its rows and columns and colorize all those cells that contain value "T".

If you cannot understand the first solution, you can use something like this that is a bit more easy on the eyes:

```
foreach (Range row in rng.Rows)
{
    foreach (Range column in row.Columns)
    {
        if (column.Value == "test")
        {
            column.Interior.Color = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. It's nice but not exactly what i asked for 

Comment: which cells do you want to select?

Comment: i want find all cells that content "Т" value

Comment: Updated my answer, that should work for your problem.